# How to display values of two textfields having auto suggestion in a third textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i have got a search form, that combines values of two texfields to a third textfield to make a query.

```
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" oninput="sea.value = 

password.value +''+ passwords.value">

            <label for="search" >Search Input:</label>

<input type="search" name="password" id="result" value="" placeholder="From..." data-

theme="h">

<label for="search" >Search Input:</label>

<input type="search" name="passwords" id="to" value="" placeholder="To..." data-theme="h">

<button class="ui-btn ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow-icon ui-btn-

e">Search</button>

<input name="sea" type="text" id="sea">

            </form>
```

but now i applied a live search effect to my textfields so that users can see suggestions and pick from the options that come out. which also works.

but i notice  the two textfields that used to be combined to form the third textfield dont combine anymore, because of the oninput action which is now overlooked because of the option of the live suggestions my textfields give, what can i do to the solve this

Comment: What have you tried to get what you want ? Any errors on the Javascript console ? Please post some code on a jsfiddle or here.

Comment: Can you give us some piece of code?? Or post a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i have combine both textfields to display in a third textfield, but beacue i have now appied auto suggestion to those two textfields, it can no longer combine them because it works based oninput. thats the error.

Comment: now u should be able to see my code above, my auto suggestion script is based on php

Answer (score 0):

use onchange event of two textfields to make sure that third field populated after values
in either textfields change

Comment: how do i effectively do this, showing from the code i gave u, please help regards

Comment: use onchange instead of oninput oninput="combinevalues();"

function combinevalues()
{
var box1=  document.getelemtnbyID('password1')
var box2=  document.getelemtnbyID('password2')
var thirdvalue=box1.value+" "+box2.value
}

Comment: am not getting this. i would really appreciate if you could do me a small sample, regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery UI to implement the auto complete search.

In jQuery UI v1.8rc3, the autocomplete widget accepts a source option which can be either a string, an array, or a callback function. If it's a string, autocomplete does a GET on that URL to get options/suggestions. If an array, autocomplete does a search, as you pointed out, for the presence of the typed chars in any position in the terms of the array. The final variant is what you want - the callback function.

From the auto complete documentation:

The third variation, the callback, provides the most flexibility, and can be used to connect any data source to Auto complete. The callback gets two arguments:

• A request object, with a single property called "term", which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the user entered "new yo" in a city field that is set to do auto complete, the request.term will hold "new yo".
• A response function, a callback which expects a single argument to contain the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and must be an array in the format allowed for simple local data: String-Array or Object-Array with label/value/both properties.

Example:

```
var wordlist= [ "about", "above", "across", "after", "against",
                "along", "among", "around", "at", "before", 
                "behind", "below", "beneath", "beside", "between", 
                "beyond", "but", "by", "despite", "down", "during", 
                "except", "for", "from", "in", "inside", "into", 
                "like", "near", "of", "off", "on", "onto", "out", 
                "outside", "over", "past", "since", "through", 
                "throughout", "till", "to", "toward", "under", 
                "underneath", "until", "up", "upon", "with", 
                "within", "without"] ; 

$("#input1").autocomplete({


// The source option can be an array of terms.  In this case, if
    // the typed characters appear in any position in a term, then the
    // term is included in the autocomplete list.
 source: function(req, responseFn) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
        var a = $.grep( wordlist, function(item,index){
            return matcher.test(item);
        });
        responseFn( a );
    }
});
```

check this link:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default

Comment: the autocomplete part isnt a problem, its just that now i cant combine  the two textfileds together because i dont need to type all through